# Enabling/triggering mousewheel effect ONLY on certain div (not fullpage)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mousewheel

I'm writing this after searching for mousewheel events in jQuery, but perhaps I'm not asking the right questions due to my lack of knowledge, and that's why I'm not finding any useful answers yet.

What I would like to achieve is a mousewheel effect that I can trigger **only inside a certain div** called #scroller. I'm using the jquery mousewheel plugin by Brandon Aaron and a script that updates the top value to the next or previous .js-slide whenever I delta scroll.

FIDDLE LINK:
I created this fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/1tmk1o6k/). As you can see, it "jumps" from slide to slide, but then the content outside #scroller is not accesible anymore! I would like it to have a normal wheelmouse behaviour :S. I also have a working url where I would like to apply this effect, if you think that's of any use.

To better explain the structure and desired effect, here's an image:

[image]

I have already tried bounding my script only to `$('#scroller').mouseover(function(){ my script });` but that didn't work. The mousewheel started out ok, it switched into jumping mode ok, but it never went back to normal after leaving the div #scroller and I don't find how to reset this behaviour.

My script right now is this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var slide = $('.js-slide');
    var sectionHeight = $(window).height();
    var slideHeight = $(slide).height();    
    var scrollingScreen = false;

        $('#scroller').mouseover(function(){

            $(slide).mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
                if ( !scrollingScreen ) {
                    scrollingScreen = true; // prevent call
                    var top = $("body").scrollTop() || $("html").scrollTop();
                    // Chrome places overflow at body, Firefox places whacks at html...
                    // Finds slide headers above/below the current scroll top
                    var candidates = $(slide).filter(function() {
                        if ( delta < 0 )
                            return $(this).offset().top > top + (1);
                        else
                            return $(this).offset().top < top - (1);
                    });
                    // one or more slides found? Update top
                    if ( candidates.length > 0 ) {
                        if ( delta < 0 )
                            top = candidates.first().offset().top;
                        else if ( delta > 0 )
                            top = candidates.last().offset().top;
                    }
                    // Perform animated scroll to the right place
                    $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop:top }, "easeInOutQuint", function() {
                        scrollingScreen = false; // Release call
                    });
                }
                return false; 
            }); // closes mousewheel

       }); // closes mouseover

});
```

Any help or insight on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Add your HTML and CSS with this and post a demo in http://jsfiddle.net . Correct errors like `$('#scroller')` <- Add Quotes; `slide.mousewheel(` <- No need to wrap in `$()` again as its already a jQuery Object. Why are you checking the scroll position of whole page using `$("body").scrollTop()`?

Comment: Thank you for the correction on the `'#scroller'`. I had it correct in my script but copied it wrong. // Ok, didn't know that. Thanks. // I check scrollTop() from the top of the body because it was first designed to work on the entire page. Now that I want to restrict it to the div #scroller, I guess I could change that to `$('#scroller').scrollTop()`. // Oh, and thank you Rory McCrossan for editing the image inline :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Finally I found it!! I reviewed the web where the plugin author records different mousewheel events, including deactivating all of them and reseting a normal scrolling mouse. There's where I found the use of the function **.unmousewheel()**, just what I wanted!

But now, as the script is not able to find further slides past de last when scrolling down, and before the first when scrolling up, it became impossible to access content before and after #scroller with the scrolling wheel. That's why I had to change a bit the script and force a jump while on the first slide or the last.

Anyway, here's the script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var slide = $('#scroller .sectioncontainer');
    var sectionHeight = $(window).height();
    var slideHeight = slide.height();
    var scrollingScreen = false;

    slide.mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
        if ( !scrollingScreen ) {
            scrollingScreen = true; // prevent call

            var top = $("body").scrollTop() || $("html").scrollTop();
            // Chrome places overflow at body, Firefox places whacks at html...

            // Finds slide headers above/below the current scroll top
            var candidates = slide.filter(function() {
                if ( delta < 0 )
                    return $(this).offset().top > top + (1/120);
                else
                    return $(this).offset().top < top - (1/120);
            });

            // one or more slides found? Update top
            if ( candidates.length > 0 ) {
                if ( delta < 0 )
                    top = candidates.first().offset().top;
                else if ( delta > 0 )
                    top = candidates.last().offset().top;
            } else{ // no more slides found
                     if ( delta < 0 )
                    top = $("#contact").offset().top;
                else if ( delta > 0 )
                    top = $("#about").offset().top;
            }

            // Perform animated scroll to the right place
            $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop:top }, "easeInOutQuint", function() {
                scrollingScreen = false; // Release call
            });
        }
        return false; 
    });

    $("#contact").unmousewheel();
    $("#about").unmousewheel();
    $("#div1").unmousewheel();
    $("#div2").unmousewheel();
    $("#div3").unmousewheel();
    $("#div4").unmousewheel();
    $("#div5").unmousewheel();
    // . . . 
    //and all other divs and sections that don't use the mousewheel

});
```

And here's the [result](http://beacabrera.es).